# C# Ошибка в decrypt

Tags: c#

Как справиться с ошибкой

```
byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
```

При декрипте выдает

> Входные данные не являются действительной строкой Base-64, поскольку
>   содержат символ в кодировке, отличной от Base 64, больше двух символов
>   заполнения или недопустимый символ среди символов заполнения.

Полный код

```
public  string Encrypt(string clearText)
    {

        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return clearText;
    } 

    public  string Decrypt(string cipherText)
    {

        cipherText = cipherText.Replace(" ", "+");
        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);//ВОТ ТУТ ОШИБКА
        string KeyBuf = EncryptionKey;
        Clipboard.SetText(KeyBuf);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return cipherText;
    }
```

Comment: 'cipherText = cipherText.Replace(" ", "+");' это что? зачем оно?

Answer (score 0):

В base64 нет символа "+" : cipherText = cipherText.Replace(" ", "+");

Comment: Удалил эту строчку, проблема осталась...

Comment: Значит в метод Decrypt приходит невалидная Base64 строка

Comment: Надо, видимо, не "удалить эту строчку", а исправить в ней замену "+" на пробел, заменой на пустую строку, т.е. на удаление символа "+". А не заменить на  пробел, как у вас.